# Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

Can anyone explain what I need to do to get past this error?

"Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority' because it is not a delegate type"

```
    private void Test(object sender)
    {
        base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
                       //some code

        }, new object[0]);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245744/invoking-wpf-dispatcher-with-anonymous-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968709/anonymous-methods-and-delegates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 SP1 and upwards, then you can add a reference to *System.Windows.Presentation.dll* and make sure you have `using System.Windows.Threading;` at the top of the file. It contains extension methods that are easier to use, and allow you to simply write:

```
base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { /* some code */ });
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 without SP1 or lower, then you'll have to cast the delegate to a concrete delegate type:

```
base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate { /* some code */ }, new object[0]);
```

Comment: Actually, the first doesn't compile using .NET 4.0 in VS 2010. Are you sure?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: For the extension method trick, you might also need to add a `using System.Windows.Threading;` directive if you don't already have it.

Comment: I have this included, but still the first code doesn't compile with an error like "Cannot convert lambda expression to "System.Delegate" as it is not a delegate type" (sorry, using German VS 2010 - no English message available :-)).

Comment: @Thorsten: Then you didn't add a reference to *System.Windows.Presentation.dll*. The method is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647516.aspx).

Comment: Ha! Right again :-) Works as soon as I add the reference.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I got confused with you passing `new object[0]` as "parameter" to `BeginInvoke` and didn't realize that this actually means "no parameters", as everything following the delegate is in the `params` collection...

I'm making an example that expects a single integer.

You want to pass parameters, so it's best to use this

```
private void Test(object sender)
{
    base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action<int>)delegate(int i)
    {
                   //some code

    }, 5);
}
```

This creates an anonymous delegate that takes an integer, converts this to an action that takes an integer and calls the delegate with the parameter `5`.

Comment: This code throws a `TargetParameterCountException` (Message="Parameter count mismatch."). This is because the delegate passed to `BeginInvoke` must have parameters matching the provided parameter array, and not simply a single parameter of type `object[]`.

Comment: Ah, I thought he's passing an array as the single parameter (`new object[0]`). I didn't realize that this means "no parameters", as it is interpreted as `params` collection. Interesting side-question: how would I pass an array object to `BeginInvoke` so I can have a delegate that expects a single `object[] array` parameter?

Comment: Instead of `new object[0]` you would provide for example `new object[] { new object[5] }`. The `Action<object[]>` would get the five-element array as its argument. That would work with the above code. Also, this has nothing to do with `params`, but rather how a delegate is invoked with `.DynamicInvoke(...)`.

Comment: Usually, a new thread isn't created when using a `Dispatcher`. The whole point of a `Dispatcher` is to run code on an existing thread.

Comment: You're right with your last comment - I'll change that. However, I disagree on the comment before that. Calling `BeginInvoke(..., new object[2])` would cause the error, as internally the array is treated as if I had called `BeginInvoke(..., null, null)`, so the delegate would have to take two nullable arguments. Calling `BeginInvoke(..., new object[0])` is equivalent to calling `BeginInvoke(...)`. Or am I totally off track here?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. You meant to send the `new object[0]` as the single parameter for `params` but instead it was construed as ignoring the `params` syntax and manually specifying the array. That is a common pitfall of `params`. Regardless, `params` itself is not responsible for mapping array elements to parameters, that is the responsibility of .NET's reflection mechanisms that can dynamically invoke a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Cast the delegate to `Action` (or to `Func<something>` if you are returning a value).

```
private void Test(object sender)
{
    base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
        //some code
    }, new object[0]);
}
```

The first parameter of the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method requires a `System.Delegate`. This is uncommon. Usually you would specify one of the `Func` or `Action` overloads. However, here it is possible to pass delegates with different signatures. Obviously anonymous delegates are not casted to `System.Delegate` implicitly.

---

**UPDATE**

I am working with .NET 3.5. In later Framework versions additional overloads of `BeginInvoke` may disturb C#'s overloading mechanism. Try

```
private void Test(object sender)
{
    base.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((System.Delegate)(Action)delegate
    {
        //some code
    }, new object[0]);
}
```

Comment: The parenthesis aren't required for a parameterless anonymous method, and in any case the above code still won't compile.

Comment: It does compile with my VS 2008. My code: `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { }, new object[0]);`

Comment: The code might behave differently with different Framework versions. Please see my last update.